# List load balancers in AWS by tag using go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

Is there a way we can list all load balancers in aws by tag name?

I could not find anything in their [SDK documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/elb/#ELB.DescribeLoadBalancers)

Can it be done? How?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the Golang AWS SDK but if it were me and I could not find it in the SDK documentation I would look up the AWS CLI documentation and find commands there since they may translate over to the SDK or worst case run system commands in Golang to execute the CLI and get the same result.

### GetResources

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html

> Returns all the tagged resources that are associated with the
>   specified tags (keys and values) located in the specified region for
>   the AWS account.

So you could use this to get all resources with a specific tag and then in Golang iterate over the results to only select the ELBs

Looks like you can filter both by tag and resource in one command:

[image: getresouce]

Looks like the command does exist for golang sdk

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/resourcegroupstaggingapi/#ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.GetResources

and I would think the options I highlighted above are available to you.

### Exec in Golang

You would use something such as exec.
https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

This tutorial may contain how to also get results back from exec
https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/12/29/shelled-out-commands-in-golang/

### Example Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/elb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/resourcegroupstaggingapi"
)

const (
    // ProviderName is the cloud provider providing loadbalancing functionality
    ProviderName = "aws"
)

// ELB is the struct implementing the lbprovider interface
type ELB struct {
    client            *elb.ELB
    elbResourceName   string
    resourceapiClient *resourcegroupstaggingapi.ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI
}

// NewELB is the factory method for ELB
func NewELB(id string, secret string, region string) (*ELB, error) {
    awsConfig := &aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String(region),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(id, secret, ""),
    }

    awsConfig = awsConfig.WithCredentialsChainVerboseErrors(true)
    sess, err := session.NewSession(awsConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unable to initialize AWS session: %v", err)
    }

    return &ELB{
        client:            elb.New(sess),
        resourceapiClient: resourcegroupstaggingapi.New(sess),
        elbResourceName:   "elasticloadbalancing",
    }, nil
}

// GetLoadbalancersByTag gets the loadbalancers by tag
func (e *ELB) GetLoadbalancersByTag(tagKey string, tagValue string) ([]string, error) {
    tagFilters := &resourcegroupstaggingapi.TagFilter{}
    tagFilters.Key = aws.String(tagKey)
    tagFilters.Values = append(tagFilters.Values, aws.String(tagValue))

    getResourcesInput := &resourcegroupstaggingapi.GetResourcesInput{}
    getResourcesInput.TagFilters = append(getResourcesInput.TagFilters, tagFilters)
    getResourcesInput.ResourceTypeFilters = append(
        getResourcesInput.ResourceTypeFilters,
        aws.String(e.elbResourceName),
    )

    resources, err := e.resourceapiClient.GetResources(getResourcesInput)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    elbs := []string{}
    for _, resource := range resources.ResourceTagMappingList {
        elbs = append(elbs, strings.Split(*resource.ResourceARN, "/")[1])
    }
    return elbs, nil
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but CLI is a dirty approach i want to avoid

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/resourcegroupstaggingapi/
Here I can see GetResources available for the Golang SDK.

Comment: Great thanks it works, posting the answer, if you guys can reopen i will post the answer

Comment: pardon would you please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Already done. Could you update your answer for using resources with this gist snippet, would help someone. https://gist.github.com/alok87/c09243f0d61772bb1a7b93ce9a295362

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over the list of ELBs and filter by Tags.

```
    svc := elbv2.New(...)

    input := &elbv2.DescribeLoadBalancersInput{
            LoadBalancerArns: []*string{},
    }

    result, _ := svc.DescribeLoadBalancers(input)

    var list_of_arns []*string
    for _, lb := range result.LoadBalancers{
            list_of_arns = append(list_of_arns, lb.LoadBalancerArn)
    }

    input2 := &elbv2.DescribeTagsInput{
            ResourceArns: list_of_arns,
    }

    result2, _ := svc.DescribeTags(input2)
    fmt.Println(result2.TagDescriptions)
```